# Same thread seems as if it's running twice but is only invoked once in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, java-threads

I have the following code under my *main*:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());  
for(inti=0;i!=Lock.totalThreads;i++) {  
    System.out.println("thread wascreated");   
    (new Thread(new MyThread())).start();   
}
System.out.println("main finished running files");
```

*MyThread* class looks like this:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    private static int threadCounter=0;
    private int myThreadId=0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(Lock.lock){
            threadCounter++;
            myThreadId=threadCounter;
        }
        System.out.println("run()");
        try {
            runMe();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void runMe() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String currentFile;
        BufferedReader in;
        System.out.println("run()");
        switch(myThreadId){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("thread1 started");
            System.out.println("thread1 finished");
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        case 2: 
            System.out.println("thread2 started");
            System.out.println("thread2 finished");
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());

        }
    }
```

And *Lock* class looks like this:

```
public class Lock {
    public static final Lock lock=new Lock();
    public static final int totalThreads=1;
}
```

And the console output is like this:

> 1
>   thread was created
>   main finished running files
>   run()
>   runMe()
>   thread1 started
>   thread1 finished
>   8
>   thread2 started
>   thread2 finished
>   8

I am having troubles to understand how come such a thing happens.
It is obvious (to me at least) that only one time a Thread is created (only once we can see **run()**, **runMe()** and **thread was created**), but twice **thread started/finished** and the **Thread ID** in the output.
 How come the **threadCounter** is incremented twice, while entering run() only once?

P.S, I am using Java 6.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're missing `break;` after both `case 1` and `case 2`.